# How do you set the expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources in IIS

Tags: caching, iis

I am using **IIS 6** and **IIS 7** as a web server.

After running *Google page speed online* , it remarks that I should be: `Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.`

And it lists a lot of plain *images* , my *javascript files* and the *style sheets*.

How can I **set this expiry date for these static files** ? I thought this was done automatically by the browser ?

Comment: Strange, earned a popular question badge on this question, but no one upvoted it.  :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Leverage browser caching:**

> Setting an expiry date or a maximum
>   age in the HTTP headers for static
>   resources instructs the browser to
>   load previously downloaded resources
>   from local disk rather than over the
>   network.
>
> http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html#LeverageBrowserCaching

To set an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources

Open IIS manager-> Click your site-> Click the HTTP Response Headers in the home page-> Click the Set Common Headers on the Actions panel -> Check Expire Web Content -> Set After 7 days (as suggested for in the page speed analysis "Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources"

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I did set this parameter to 7 days, but testing today using Google page speed still produces the same warning. I did not, however, restart the website. Do you happen to know if a restart is necessary for this parameter to take effect ?

Comment: @edelcom you can restart the IIS and check again.
Open IIS Manager and navigate to that setting again and double check. and if you can simulate the setting locally.it would be a good idea for testing

Comment: Google say `(We prefer Expires over Cache-Control: max-age because it is is more widely supported.) Do not set it to more than one year in the future, as that violates the RFC guidelines.` And unfortunately IIS doesn't let you set dynamic expires headers. This means their pagespeed tool will always report you needing to "Leverage browser caching"

Comment: @Ramiel this seems to set the expiration on all content, but would it not be better to set expiration based on type of content, e.g. css/javascript/images/aspx? separately? If this is the case, how to do so? Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisS FWIW PageSpeed seems to be satisfied with using max-age on IIS, [as per this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24483447/231851).

Comment: i tried this but i have a issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704618/asp-mvc-expire-headers-not-set-for-static-contents) is my question,  expire header is not set

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the google tool complains if you don't set both the Cache-Control max-age and the Expires header, IIS just sets the max-age, which should be fine really. You can confirm by using chrome or firebug and looking at the Net Debug panel and inspecting the response headers.

Answer (score 2):

setting expiry date for static files should be done in Web.config file for IIS. I don't have much knowledge in ISS, but found this on web

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

```
<caching>
   <profiles>
     <add extension=".php" policy="DisableCache" kernelCachePolicy="DisableCache" />
     <add extension=".html" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="14:00:00:00" />
   </profiles>
</caching>
```

The above code will enable caching for .html files for a maximum of 14 days. For .php files, ensure that no caching is performed.

For more refer http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache