# IE, Chrome, and Mozilla, all somehow pulling cache of php/html file with error, even though it is corrected on the file server

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, caching

This is very strange.  I had code where I wrote in jQuery

```
alert($x+","$y);
```

This of course should have been written as

```
alert($x+","+$y);
```

I corrected the file, and uploaded it to my web server.  When I attempt to view it in any of the above browsers, I check the page source, and it shows it as being corrected.

Then when I run it with debugger (in all three), it comes up as having the old error still there.  I cannot help but think this is picking up some old cache on my laptop.  I went into each manually and deleted the cache.  I also ran CCleaner to double check and clear the cache.  No change.  I even deleted and uninstalled Mozilla and Chrome, and they are STILL picking up the old version of the file.

My question is this...is it that all three browsers are picking up an old cache, or is my web server somehow flaking out and still serving up the old version of the file?

Any thoughts?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: I'd suggest you look the network tab in the Chrome browser and see what exactly is coming over the wire.  That will tell you whether your issue is on your server or in your browser, though it seems likely that it's on the server.

Comment: @jfriend00 , when I look at the network tab on first download and checkout preview (this is in chrome), I see the jquery as it should be.  Then when I reload it, the network tab preview option still shows the jquery as being corrected.  However, it still shows the error of the original code in the console.     What else should I be looking for in the network tab?

Comment: Are you 200% sure you're looking at the right place in the code when you check what's coming over the wire?  Could it be that you've fixed it one place, but not another?

Comment: @jfriend00 , I also just checked the RESPONSE tab under Network, and it shows the error....  So what exactly is happening here?   Any thoughts?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yepp, 100% certain, I use unique variable names, and these are local to a function anyways.  Good idea though.  Anything else ?

Comment: If the response tab shows the wrong code, then it's coming from your server.  You will have to go troubleshoot there.  Perhaps it has some caching itself, different server environments have different capabilities in this regard.

Comment: @jfriend00 Any chance you could expound on what it is that is actually happening ?  I don't really understand the different between the "preview" and "response" areas of the Network tab....can you elaborate on that ?   Thanks! :)

Comment: In Chrome, Preview is supposed to be a visual look at the resource - it's more meaningful for things like images.  Response should be what that HTTP request returned.  If the response came from the cache, the headers tab will show that with a "(from cache)" indication.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [this free online tool from pingdom dot com](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/)

It might show you which images are being requested or not?

Try looking at the waterfall tab for the image filename maybe?

**Awesome** tool for finding bottlenecks so you can look for clues as to how to speed up a slow site!

Comment: this has nothing to do with the images downloading or not.  It's about jQuery code that resides in a corrected state on the web server, yet is coming up as older and broken on the three main browsers I checked it with.

Comment: Oops! got confused. The code is in a file right? Is the file visible in the waterfall tab. Sorry but that tool isn't just for images - it shows you all http requests, at least I think it does!

Comment: Can you get the .htaccess file and see what the offending file's expires headers are set to? see this site --> http://www.paulund.co.uk/set-expire-headers-in-htaccess ASSUMING it is a file!

Comment: I actually have no htaccess files setup on the server, it is windows based, not apache, and to my knowledge they only work on apache...unless I am incorrect about that.

Answer (score 0):

@ Everybody else - I am not a solutions provider, I just find clues and give suggestions that might help - sorry if that's not the correct approach on STOF but in the last 2 years googling and finding answers is the only way that worked for me...so that's why I use and recommend this method...even if you can go around in cirlces for a few hours sometimes!

---

@OP - I looked in to Windows server and a .htaccess file and you're right, that is an Apache specific feature but...
Windows based servers do have an equivalent called a web.config file and it allows you to set "expires" header directives that can prevent undesired caching

I don't use .net or Microsoft products for web dev so I'm not an expert but I can do a Google search and check stuff out.

[Here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache) is a Microsoft site that mentions IIS and caching

Excerpt:

> Client Cache clientCache
>
> The  element of the  element specifies cache-related HTTP headers that IIS 7 and later sends to Web clients, which control how Web clients and proxy servers will cache the content that IIS 7 and later returns.
>
> For example, the httpExpires attribute specifies a date and time that the content should expire, and IIS 7 and later will add an HTTP "Expires" header to the response. The value for the httpExpires attribute must be a fully-formatted date and time that follows the specification in RFC 1123. For example:...

[Here](http://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/readings/handouts/SE435/HTTP/node24.html) is a site that talks about cache control

> Cache-Control HTTP Headers
>
> Although the Expires header is useful, it's still somewhat limited; there are many situations where content is cacheable, but the HTTP/1.0 protocol lacks methods of telling caches what it is, or how to work with it. HTTP/1.1 introduces a new class of headers, the Cache-Control response headers, which allow web publishers to define how pages should be handled by caches. They can be broken down into the following general categories:
>   Restrictions on what are cacheable; these may only be imposed by the origin server.
>   Restrictions on what may be stored by a cache; these may be imposed by either the origin server or the user agent.
>   Modifications of the basic expiration mechanism; these may be imposed by either the origin server or the user agent.
>   Controls over cache revalidation and reload; these may only be imposed by a user agent.
>   Control over transformation of entities.
>   Extensions to the caching system. 
>   What is Cacheable? 
>   ...

Perhaps you could start there?

Another thing I say (who am I?) is an ***absolute must*** is;

1. get the Firefox web browser
2. an extension  or add-on for it called Firebug (which gives you enhanced web developer tools)
3. another add-on called Y-slow which finds bottle-necks in web-page loading etc.

**You might not use Firefox but I'd say it might be useful just for this 1 thing!**

Finally [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221408/http-expire-headers-in-asp-net-with-web-config) question on STOF seems to mention many of the things I've been digging up and could be useful??

Excerpt.

> I'm trying to get YSlow to give me an A on the "Add Expires header" section by setting the web.config file.
>
> I've been looking around and this is what I put in based on what's out there:
>
> This is what I'm seeing in Firebug:

```
<staticContent>
<clientCache httpExpires="15.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseExpires"/>
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

> Response Headers
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
> Date: Sun, 28 Aug 2011 13:54:50 GMT
> X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
> Cache-Control: private
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
> Content-Length: 24255
> Connection: Close
> ...
> ```

Hope you figure it out!